# Music Player Python

Tags: python, python-vlc

I m building music player in python. Program working for one file or if i add playlist prepared in advance. I have a question, is there a way to dynamic add file to playlist in vlc lib ? that is add path to file, tick and play this file ? or i have to change lib to pygame ?

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Python Simple Player")
root.geometry("600x500")

#List of audio files
fileListFrame = tk.Listbox(root, bg="aqua", fg="green", width=60)
fileListFrame.pack(pady=20)

#box to print audioFile tag's
audioTagBox = tk.Listbox(root, bg="white", fg="green", width=60)
audioTagBox.pack(pady=20)

file='Alex2.mp3'

class music_Player():
    def __init__(self, audio_file):
    # creating a vlc instance
        vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
    # creating a media player
        self.player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    # creating a media
        media = vlc_instance.media_new(audio_file)
    # setting media to the player
        self.player.set_media(media)
    
    def btn_play(self): #def play
        song = fileListFrame.get(ACTIVE)
        audio =music_Player(song)
        self.player.play()
    
    def btn_pause(self): #def pauzy
        self.player.pause()
    
    def btn_stop(self): #def stopu
        self.player.stop()

    def btn_next(self):
        pass

    def btn_prev(self):
        pass

audio =music_Player(file)
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='audio/', title="Choose song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"), ))
    fileListFrame.insert(END, song)
my_menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

file_menu = tk.Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label = "Exit")
```

Comment: This question isn't about `tkinter` so please remove the `tkinter` tag.

Comment: And what is then main question??

Comment: is there a way to dynamic add file to playlist in vlc lib ? that is add path to file, tick and play this file ? or i have to change lib to pygame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pygame is a very good option for this
first before anything do `pip install pygame`

```
import pygame
class your_app_name(self, tk.Tk):
   def __init__(*args **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       pygame.init()
       #GUI code instead of root, though you can use self and you don't need to create it either and for using any of these function do self.func_name
   def play(self):
       pygame.mixer.music.load(your_file_name)
       pygame.mixer.music.play()
   def stop(self):
       pygame.mixer.music.stop()
app = your_app_name()#inside of brackets you can pass arguments which you would pass to tk.Tk()
#for doing things like root.geometry() do app.geometry()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: For my case the better option is to change lib to pygame. Thanks for help. This link is for half-finished program if someone is interested https://github.com/wolfraine/PythonMusicPlayer/blob/main/player.py

Answer (score 0):

You got the folder path, right? then you can simply do this:

```
import os
allmp3files=[x for x in os.listdir("folder/path") if x.endswith(".mp3")]
```

Now you got list of all mp3 files from that directory. Now you can use `allmp3files[0/1/2/3....]` as usual. or there is your `fileListFrame(Menu)` You can simply add all these files in that menu and ......